# Java API - Null warning on custom method checker

Tags: java, api, api-design

During the designing of my API. I had some utility methods that are to be used in non-spring environment. Null checks and all exists in this method. But the issue is that **Null Warning** is being generated by **IntelliJ Idea**, and classified as **Bug** by **sonar**

Intelli J Idea Snap

[image: IntelliJ Idea]

Sonar Snap

[image: Sonar Snap]

Actual Function code

[image: Actual Code]

PS: We don't want to import spring-core or checker framework on our project.

Please suggest what to make it like in spring. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hm - the problem here is that Sonar does not 'know' that `CollectionUtil.isNotEmpty` checks for null, and it would have to analyze the code of the dependency to find out.

Comment: There seems to be a whitelist of methods that sonar recognizes, perhaps that could be updated to include the one you want to use. There have also been real False Positive- bugs around this topic recently (e.g. [this one](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sometimes-rule-squid-s2259-is-false-positive-with-method-in-whitelist/20880/3) and [this one](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/apache-commons-maputils-isnotempty-is-not-recognize-by-sonar-scanning/35935)), so make sure your Sonar version is up-to-date.

Comment: Hi @Hulk, I try it by adding to whitelisted methods in sonar